# Question regarding setting up a new website in htdocs folder

Tags: linux, web, web-config

Today I moved my website to a new hosting company (Verio). I've done this lots of times before, and I know that your website should go inside the "htdocs" folder.

Now usually when I use FileZilla, I can do a "Right Click" on a filename to get the URL of that file.  This is the result of my root default file: ftp://test@test.com/www/htdocs/Research/index.php

However, on the web, the true URL of my default file is: www.test.com/Research/index.php

My index.php file is in the website root folder.   Does anyone know why FileZilla would include the server folders "www/htdocs" as part of the URL?  These folders should not normally be visible to the user.

OR, is this look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ftp url is correct. Your FTP account has access to the two folders (`www/htdocs/`) before the document root, as most hosting providers provide.

You are also correct to assume that http access is limited to the document root. (Meaning they cannot see `www/htdocs/`)

Comment: Thank you...I was unfamiliar with this host setup..your answer confirms this was the right way.  Thanks.